# How to create a CRON job which runs a bazel command

Tags: cron, cron-task, bazel

I need to create a CRON job which executes the bazel command `bazel-bin`. I tried setting up the following CRON job `* * * * * ubuntu /home/ubuntu/serving/ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_export`

However, the CRON job does not get successfully scheduled and the command is not executed. Could someone guide me how to schedule a CRON job for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The CRON job is successfully running using the following `* * * * * (cd /home/ubuntu/serving/; bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_export)`. Since while running the bazel binaries we need to cd to the    target.runfiles/workspace_name directory, thus the above-mentioned command works fine.